# SH script getting file with regula expression

Tags: regex, shell, sh

I have directory where some process is generating daily reports to.

Which looks like:

```
[root@test raportdaily]$ ls -l
razem 538332
-rwxrwxr--+ 1 raport raport    541526 02-17 06:06 REPORT-SYSTEM_2014-02-17_060623.csv
-rwxrwxr--+ 1 raport raport    542718 02-18 06:22 REPORT-SYSTEM_2014-02-18_062229.csv
-rwxrwxr--+ 1 raport raport    542886 02-19 06:28 REPORT-SYSTEM_2014-02-19_062826.csv
```

Thing that I can't deal with is that the last 6 digits at the name of the file are in format `HourMinuteSecond` and are different each day.

I would like to create a `shell script` which will be able to load this file ( I need to knew the name) and change it's `character set`.

If I knew the exact name of this file I can access it directly with:

```
#!/bin/sh

iconv -c --from=utf8 --to=utf8 /home/raport/REPORT-SYSTEM_2014-02-19_062826.csv
```

How Can I use regular expression which looks like:

```
REPORT-SYSTEM_2014-02-19_.*.csv
```

In order to use match of this `regex` in `iconv` function?

Comment: In shell reg-exp, a period ('.') means a period, not 'any character' as in language reg-exp. You can just do `REPORT-SYSTEM_2014-02-19_*.csv` OR if you really sure about 6 numbers at the end, the `?` char is shell reg-exp for 1 char, so `REPORT-SYSTEM_2014-02-19_??????.csv` . Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it easily with grep:

```
FILE=`ls /home/raport/ | grep "REPORT-SYSTEM_2014-02-19_.*.csv"`
iconv -c --from=utf8 --to=utf8 $FILE
```

Make note of the backticks used in the first line.

Comment: Srsly I am rly dumb ... How can I use result of grep as a variable in `sh` ?:/

Comment: I have lot to learn... It looks so easy. Thank You Vasili Syrakis!

Comment: No problem :) bash is great.